# how to avoid the blank line printed before the output in this program?

Tags: c, scanf, whitespace, c-strings

my code is below
how to avoid the blank line printed before the required output?
the question is to print the batsman with maximum runs.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        int n,runs,maxRuns=0;
        char bat[100],maxBat[100];
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%[^,],%d",&bat,&runs);
            if(runs>maxRuns){
                maxRuns=runs;
                strcpy(maxBat,bat);
            }
        }
        printf("%s",maxBat);
    
    }
```

the output i'm getting is

[image]

Comment: I may be mistaken, but a potential problem might be, that you are not consuming the newline character (`\n`) at the end of your scanf.
This may result in said newline character being consumed at the start of the following line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
scanf( " %[^,],%d", bat, &runs );
```

See the blank before the first conversion specifier,

Also instead of `&bat` use `bat` because the type of the expression  `&bat` (`char( * )[100]`) is not `char *` as it is required by the conversion specifier `%[`.

Comment: `&bat` "works" in that case but only because `bat` is an array. With a pointer it's UB